Excel VBA 438 error when using thisworkbook and word application in same script
I'm testing out a method for a bigger project and am running into 438 errors for this script. If I grab the worksheet first, the error comes from calling word.application, if I grab the word doc stuff first, the 438 throws when I grab the worksheet. I cannot find any viable solutions for this, though I did try early binding, and have begun copying the document first so that it's always working in a fresh Word doc to avoid other conflicts. What else could be the issue here?
Option Explicit

Sub Merge()
    Dim WordDoc As Object, N As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    'i = Range("C2").Value  'pulls length of list from an excel function located in cell C2 =COUNTIF(B4:B5005,"*")
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim source As String
    Dim destination As String
    Dim xlobj As Object
    Set xlobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    source = "C:\...\MERGE TEMPLATE - CONSTRUCTION LOAN AGREEMENT.docx"
    destination = "C:\...\WORKING - CONSTRUCTION LOAN AGREEMENT.docx"
    xlobj.CopyFile source, destination, True
    Set xlobj = Nothing
    Set wordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    wordApp.Options.SaveInterval = 0
    Set WordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\...\WORKING - CONSTRUCTION LOAN AGREEMENT.docx")
    WordDoc.Visible = True
    Dim dataws As Worksheet
    Set dataws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Merge Fields")
    N = dataws.Range("a1:b1").Value 'test row
    Print (N)
   'For j = 1 To i
    With wordApp
        With WordDoc.Content.Find
            .Text = N(1, 1)
            .Replacement.Text = N(1, 2)
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
    End With
    'Next j
    wordApp.ActiveDocument.Save
    wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    wordApp.Quit

    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
End Sub


Where exactly is the error?

@TimWilliams in this version of the script, it occurs when attemping this line:
Set dataws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Merge Fields")

WordDoc.Visible = True did you mean wordApp.Visible = True?  Document doesn't have a Visible property.

No, but admittedly, that portion of the code is from StackOverflow, so I'm not sure if that's correct or not.

You're getting Error 438 on Set dataws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Merge Fields")  ?  That looks fine to me.

That got me further down the script, thank you!
I'm not sure why the error was thrown after that, as it works fine with the wordApp.Visible change. More debugging now, but this answers this question. Add as an answer and I'll accept it.

WordDoc.Visible = True

should be
wordApp.Visble = True

Document doesn't have a Visible property.
